# Sqoop Merge tool to generate output in single file

Tags: apache, hadoop, hdfs, sqoop, parquet

Currently i am executing below command

> sqoop merge --new-data  /home/part1/part-m-00000 --onto 
>   /home/part2/part-m-00000 --target-dir /home/merged --jar-file
>   /home/hadoop/myjar.jar --class-name myjar --merge-key id

Everything works fine except merge generates output in multiple part files, as this is mapreduce task in hadoop it uses multiple reducers.

Part files are parquet files, i want to create single file, as the same file will be input for my next process, and next process is to run a Apache spark job on same extracted file.

How can i force output of sqoop merge into single file? Any suggestion on this?

Thanks,

-Jackson

Answer (score 0):

What I did when I needed to do this is:

1. Create a new target file
2. After Sqoop command has run, go to directory where all part files are 
   created
3. Execute cat * >> target_file

Not sure if that will work for you as I do not have enough details to work with in your example.

Assumption here is you are executing sqoop command from shell script.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Sam S, i have [Users] table, which i need to load data in hdfs incrementally into single parquet file, and this file will be input for another process that is a spark program. So solution what you suggest is good for csv file formats. Yes i am executing sqoop from shell and sqoop version is 1.4.6

Comment: I would suggest you add that information in your question in order for others to provide expected answer.
Yes, I am working with delimited file.